# High Charts Stacked Bar Drilldown

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have to generate a stacked bar chart with drill down option.How do i achieve it dynamically through json ajax.I have four levels of drill down.When i click a column it should get specific values of that column in that way it proceed to 4 levels.At the same time i should have a back option to navigate to the previous section.Can any one suggest me with a solution?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: like this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown ?

Comment: add what you have done i mean your code to be able to get help

Comment: I'm working on figuring out this now... will let you know once I get it working.  The problem is when you do a "stacked" bar chart its hard to figure out which category in the stack they clicked on.